# Vim minibufexpl and taglist ctrl+tab switch

Tags: vim

I have two of the most popular plugins installed - [minibufexpl.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=159) and [taglist.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=273).

Each plugin works very well separately. When I have taglist opened and I click on several different tabs in minibufexpl, the buffer changes and with it also taglist menu is changed. The problem is when I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to move between buffers and have taglist menu opened at the same time. What happens then is that actually the contents of the taglist menu gets populated with the new buffer (instead of my main portion of the window).

These are the commands that I use:

```
" --------------------
" TagList
" --------------------
" F4: Switch on/off TagList
nnoremap <silent> <F4> :TlistToggle<CR>
" TagListTagName - Used for tag names
highlight MyTagListTagName gui=bold guifg=Black guibg=Orange
" TagListTagScope - Used for tag scope
highlight MyTagListTagScope gui=NONE guifg=Blue
" TagListTitle - Used for tag titles
highlight MyTagListTitle gui=bold guifg=DarkRed guibg=LightGray
" TagListComment - Used for comments
highlight MyTagListComment guifg=DarkGreen
" TagListFileName - Used for filenames
highlight MyTagListFileName gui=bold guifg=Black guibg=LightBlue
"let Tlist_Ctags_Cmd = $VIM.'/vimfiles/ctags.exe' " location of ctags tool
let Tlist_Show_One_File = 1 " Displaying tags for only one file~
let Tlist_Exist_OnlyWindow = 1 " if you are the last, kill yourself
let Tlist_Use_Right_Window = 1 " split to the right side of the screen
let Tlist_Sort_Type = "order" " sort by order or name
let Tlist_Display_Prototype = 0 " do not show prototypes and not tags in the taglist window.
let Tlist_Compart_Format = 1 " Remove extra information and blank lines from the taglist window.
let Tlist_GainFocus_On_ToggleOpen = 1 " Jump to taglist window on open.
let Tlist_Display_Tag_Scope = 1 " Show tag scope next to the tag name.
let Tlist_Close_On_Select = 1 " Close the taglist window when a file or tag is selected.
let Tlist_Enable_Fold_Column = 0 " Don't Show the fold indicator column in the taglist window.
let Tlist_WinWidth = 40


"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
"                               minibufexpl                               "
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
let g:miniBufExplMapCTabSwitchBufs = 1 "Map control-tab and control-shift-tab for switching between buffers
let g:miniBufExplUseSingleClick = 1 "Change buffer with single click on a buffer
let g:miniBufExplModSelTarget = 1 "If you use other explorers like TagList you can (As of 6.2.8) put:
let g:miniBufExplTabWrap = 1 " make tabs show complete (no broken on two lines)
let g:miniBufExplMaxSize = 1 " <max lines: defualt 0> setting this to 0 will mean the window gets as big as needed to fit all your buffers.
```

Comment: minibufexpl is *really* outdated. GVim supports tabs natively for ages, and does it much better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just ran into the same problem. It seems to be solved by using an already existing FuzzyFinder fix for TagList as well inside the `CycleBuffer()` function.

```
1598,1600c1598,1601
<   " Don't bother autoupdating the MBE window, and skip the FuzzyFinder window
<   " (Thanks toupeira!)
<   if (bufname('%') == '-MiniBufExplorer-' || bufname('%') == '[fuf]')
---
>   " Don't bother autoupdating the MBE window, and skip the FuzzyFinder and
>   " TagList  window
>   " (Thanks toupeira!) 
>   if (bufname('%') == '-MiniBufExplorer-' || bufname('%') == '[fuf]' || bufname('%') == '__Tag_List__')
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem. The change I made was what you proposed. I wrapped the whole CycleBuffer() function with an IF statement:
if !(bufname('%') == '-MiniBufExplorer-' || bufname('%') == '[fuf]' || bufname('%') == '__Tag_List__')

Comment: Tag_List has double underscore in front and behind but SO formatting deletes it